# x/net/http2: increased memory use with ForceAttemptHTTP2

Tags: go, http, http2

In my golang application we were using the http Client with custom TLS config, and as per the golang's x/net/http package if we provide a custom TLS Config then the support for http/2 will be disabled. So for enabling the http/2 support with custom TLS config I enabled the flag `ForceAttemptHTTP2` flag, but with that I'm seeing a 200MB of memory spike in my application.

Is this an expected result with using http2 in golang? I'm expecting it can't be since 200MB is a very significant number. My application with just http/1.1 enabled was running at ~380MB, but with http/2 support enabled the memory usage increases to ~580-600MB.

I'm running this application with a 800 hosts setup. To drill down the problem I did memory profiling for my application using the golang profiling tool `pprof`, and figured [readLoop](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.4:src/net/http/h2_bundle.go;l=9231) of `http2ClientConn` and [ReadFrame](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/http2/frame.go#L493) of `http2Framer` was consuming the most memory.

To check whether the ForceAttemptHTTP2 is culprit or not, I directly provided transport from http/2 package of golang, but was seeing the same result, and came to conclusion that http/2 itself was consuming the memory.

Is there any way to contain this memory usage while using http/2?
Attaching profiling results for more reference.

1. Profile results without http/2 enabled:

[Without http/2 enabled profile - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ug45.png)

[Without http/2 enabled profile - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4idIv.png)

2. Profile results with http/2 enabled:

[With http/2 enabled profile - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvOh.png)

[With http/2 enabled profile - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bser0.png)